# Query time of ms access on network

Tags: visual-studio-2005, network-drive, ms-access-2000

A ms access 2000 mdb file is hosted on a network drive. Inside this mdb, tbl_History table has **42,223** records. Every month, new **2,400** records are stored on this table.

A customized application developed by VS 2005 is queried on this table. The query is like this -

```
SELECT Top 1 MEMonth, MEYear FROM tbl_History WHERE SnapDate IN (SELECT MAX(SnapDate) FROM tbl_History WHERE CompanyCode = 'ABC'
```

To get the query result, it takes a minute. Is there any way to fine-tune the query time?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the table definition?  Sounds like some index optimization could be very helpful here: that's just not that much data, even with MS Access & via a network.

Comment: @ Will, there is an AutoNumber field but there is no primary key or index key. We need to keep the 5 year records. It seems 144, 000 records. May I know what kind of index optimization is suitable?

Comment: Regarding my query, I will change the system flow. I have a question - if total records is 159, 963 and index is already set, is there any way to speed up the query time?

Comment: it speeds up after putting the database under the root of network drive.